# How to update MVC model clientside with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

In a ASP.NET MVC project I'm uploading image files to web server using FineUploader jQuery plugin. File uploading part works fine, but now I need to save the uploaded image names to database with the corresponding model details (Product Details with Product Image names).

Models :

```
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual IEnumerable<ProductImage> Images { get; set; } 
}

public class ProductImage
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
}
```

This is my HTML & JavaScript code to upload the file & display uploaded file in the page when the upload is completed

```
...
<div id="fine-uploader"></div>
<div id="divImgs">
   <ul>
   </ul>
</div>
....

<script>
    function createUploader() {
        var uploader = new qq.FineUploader({
            element: document.getElementById('fine-uploader'),
            debug: true,
            request: {
                endpoint: '@Url.Action("UploadFile", "Upload")'
            },
            validation: {
                allowedExtensions: ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'gif', 'png']
            },
            deleteFile: {
                enabled: true,
                forceConfirm: true,
                endpoint: '@Url.Action("DeleteFile", "Upload")'
            },
            callbacks: {
                onComplete: function (id, fileName, responseJSON) {
                    if (responseJSON.success) {
                        $('#divImgs ul').append(
                            $('<li>').append(
                                $('<img>').click(
                                    function DeleteFileCall() {
                                        $.ajax({
                                            type: "POST",
                                            url: '@Url.Action("DeleteFile", "Upload")' + '/' + fileName,
                                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                            dataType: "html"
                                        });
                                        $(this).parent().remove();
                            }).attr('src', responseJSON.uploadedFilePath))
                        );
                    }
                }
            }
        });


        }

        window.onload = createUploader;
</script>
```

How can I add the uploaded file names to Model with javascript & update the database only when user saves model data.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a Fine Uploader question as you are asking specifically about server-side code that doesn't really involve the library.  Also, you should be using the Fine Uploader jQuery plug-in, and I'm not sure why you have the delete file feature turned on AND are sending your own delete file ajax requests.

Comment: @RayNicholus Yes I just removed the [FineUploader] tag.. also with the second point you are correct.. Actually I tried `deleteFile` function in `FineUploader` but later realized I need own delete method to delete previously added images (when editing a existing product), but forgot to remove the FineUploader `deleteFile` method... :(

Comment: I also suggest you use Fine Uploader's jQuery plug-in, since you are already using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

if you're uploading a Stream body in your controller, you can pass the filename as a query string parameter and map that to a function parameter for saving later.

example from another project

```
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/AddImage/{filename}", Method="POST")]
public PrimitiveResponse AddImage(string filename, Stream imageData)
{
    //magic happens here
}
```

Comment: The filename in this case will be included in the header of a multipart boundary.  The file is sent via a multipart encoded POST request.